# Php: want to print first two name of string array on first line and remaining names print on next line

Tags: php, arrays, string

I want to print first two name of string array on first line and remaining names print on next line.

```
<?php 
$array = array("johnny bairstow alex hales jonh marush","Marcelo nash tim pane alexender","chaudary Mian 
Muhammad Aqeel shaib ");

for ($i=0; $i < count($array) ; $i++) { 
$len = strlen($array[$i]);
$string =  $array[$i];
for ($j = 8; $j < 9 ; $j++) { 
    $string[$j] ='\n';
}


echo $string."</br>";
 }
?>
```

Output Should be:

```
johnny doe
alex hales jonh marush
Marcelo Nash
tim pane alexender
chaudary Mian 
Muhammad  Aqeel shaib
```

Comment: johny doe could have been johny bairstow..

Comment: what would be the output if the first string in the array contains just 3 words instead of 4 ?

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure about the total of string inside the array, you can ue explode() function

```
<?php 
$array = array("johnny doe alex hales","Marcelo nash tim pane","Mian 
Muhammad Aqeel shaib");

for ($i=0; $i < count($array) ; $i++) { 
    $len = strlen($array[$i]);
    $string =  explode(" ",  $array[$i]);
    echo $string[0] . " " . $string[1] . "<br>" .
    $string[2] . " " . $string[3] . "<br>";
}
?>
```

Pay attention, if are not 4 strings inside the array will be return and error

**Edit:**

This example is performed and you can use with 3 total strings withouth returning errors. I am suggesting to you, to use this code

```
<?php 
$array = array("johnny doe alex ","Marcelo nash tim pane","Mian 
Muhammad Aqeel shaib");

for ($i=0; $i < count($array) ; $i++) { 

    $len = strlen($array[$i]); 
    $string =  explode(" ",  $array[$i]);

    for( $n=0; $n < count($string); $n++ ){

        echo $string[$n];
        echo ( $n & 1 ) ? '<br>' : ' ' ;

    }

 }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
<?php 
$array = array("johnny doe alex hales","Marcelo nash tim pane","Mian 
               Muhammad Aqeel shaib");

foreach($array as $string) {        

    foreach(explode(' ', $string) as $index => $name) {

        $br_new_string = true;

        echo $name . ' ';

        if(1 == $index % 2) {           
            echo '<br>';

            $br_new_string = false;         
        }
    }

    echo $br_new_string ? '<br>' : '';
}
```

output :

```
johnny doe 
alex hales 
Marcelo nash 
tim pane 
Mian Muhammad 
Aqeel shaib
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative and short solution:

```
$data = ["johnny doe alex hales", "Marcelo nash tim pane", "Mian Muhammad Aqeel shaib"];

// Make them all into one string and explode the values on space
$names  = explode(' ', implode(' ', $data));

for ($i = 0; $i < count($names); $i++) {
    // Echo the name for the index, add one to the index and echo the next one.
    echo $names[$i++] . ' ' . $names[$i] . '<br />';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by finding the second space in the string, then replace it by what you want :

```
foreach($array as $string) 
{
    $sndSpacePos = strpos($string, ' ', strpos($string, ' ')+1); //the offset for strpos is set right after the first space so it found the second one
    echo substr($string, 0, $sndSpacePos).'<br>'.substr($string, $sndSpacePos+1).'<br>'; //echo the concatenation of string parts before and after the second space with a <br> in the middle 
}
```

It avoid using explode and a second loop.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php 
$data = array(
    "johnny bairstow alex hales jonh marush",
    "Marcelo nash tim pane alexender",
    "chaudary Mian Muhammad Aqeel shaib"
);

$output = [];
foreach($data as $names) {
    $first    = strtok($names, ' ');
    $second   = strtok(' ');
    $the_rest = strtok(null);
    $output[] = $first . ' ' . $second;
    $output[] = $the_rest;
}
var_export($output);
```

Output:

```
array (
  0 => 'johnny bairstow',
  1 => 'alex hales jonh marush',
  2 => 'Marcelo nash',
  3 => 'tim pane alexender',
  4 => 'chaudary Mian',
  5 => 'Muhammad Aqeel shaib',
)
```